# can't install g++ (worked fine before?)

Tags: apt, g++

Came back to my machine today, g++ won't run from the command line.

output from `sudo apt-get install g++`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx : Depends: dkms but it is not installable
         Depends: linux-headers-generic but it is not installable or
                  linux-headers but it is not installable
         Conflicts: fglrx-driver
 fglrx-amdcccle : Conflicts: fglrx-control
 fglrx-amdcccle-updates : Conflicts: fglrx-control
 fglrx-dev : Conflicts: fglrx-driver-dev
 fglrx-updates : Depends: dkms but it is not installable
                 Depends: linux-headers-generic but it is not installable or
                          linux-headers but it is not installable
                 Conflicts: fglrx-driver
 fglrx-updates-dev : Conflicts: fglrx-driver-dev
 nvidia-settings-updates : Depends: screen-resolution-extra (>= 0.12) but it is not installable
```

apt log:

```
Start-Date: 2013-08-02  10:52:41
Commandline: apt-get install cpp-
Remove: x11-apps:i386 (7.6+5ubuntu1), libgnome2-0:i386 (2.32.1-2ubuntu1.1), libidl-common:i386 (0.8.14-0.2ubuntu2), x11-xserver-utils:i386 (7.6+3), g++:i386 (4.6.3-1ubuntu5), cpp:i386 (4.6.3-1ubuntu5), gcc:i386 (4.6.3-1ubuntu5), libidl0:i386 (0.8.14-0.2ubuntu2), libbonobo2-0:i386 (2.32.1-0ubuntu1.1), x11-session-utils:i386 (7.6+2), acpi-support:i386 (0.140.1), x11-xserver-utils-lts-quantal:i386 (7.7~3ubuntu1~precise1), liborbit2:i386 (2.14.19-0.1ubuntu1), xorg:i386 (7.6+12ubuntu2), libgnome2-bin:i386 (2.32.1-2ubuntu1.1)
End-Date: 2013-08-02  10:53:00

Start-Date: 2013-08-02  13:58:26
Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Remove: xorg-docs-core:i386 (1.6-1ubuntu2), g++-4.6:i386 (4.6.3-1ubuntu5), x11-xfs-utils:i386 (7.6+1), toshset:i386 (1.76-2), acpid:i386 (2.0.10-1ubuntu3), xinit:i386 (1.3.1-1), libbonobo2-common:i386 (2.32.1-0ubuntu1.1), libstdc++6-4.6-dev:i386 (4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
End-Date: 2013-08-02  13:58:38
```

apt sources:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20130213)]/ precise main restricted


deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted


deb ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted


deb ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe


deb ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse


deb ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted
deb-src ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted
deb ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe
deb-src ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe
deb ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security multiverse
deb-src ht.tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security multiverse


# deb ht.tp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src ht.tp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner


deb ht.tp://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src ht.tp://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main

deb ht.tp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise restricted main
```

Can anyone tell me whats going on here?

Comment: Try installing the packages on the first `Remove:` line (`x11-apps`, etc). Also, are there more messages after `2013-08-02  13:58:26`?

Comment: There are no more messages after the first. I let someone else use my machine while out for lunch. After talking to them, it seems like they tried to install cpp->dia, specifically by running sudo apt-get install cpp->dia.

Comment: sorry, should've mentioned I had to put those dots in there (I cannot post more than 2 links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, do not install NVIDIA and ATI drivers at the same time, it causes several headaches. Run:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx* nvidia* && sudo apt-get -f install
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf ## This is expected to fail in some cases.
sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-core-lts-quantal
```

To repair your installation. Then install `build-essentials` instead of just `g++`, it will install `gcc`, `g++`, `make`, etc.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essetials
```

### About your `sources.list`

Your `sources.list` file has erroneous entries, instead `ht.tp://` it should be `http://`, please edit and run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Here are the sources:

Comment: Also, I get this:rm: cannot remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf': No such file or directory

Comment: This answer helped a lot. I was able to run sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, and then sudo apt-get install build-essentials after executing the first command in your answer. Everything works again, thanks!